# Start wvdial on boot from crontab

Tags: cron, wvdial

I'm trying to get work crontab, I'm editing crontab with `sudo crontab -e`.

After that I add the line

```
@reboot wvdial
```

at the end of file, theoretically, every boot the computer connect with `wvdial` but it doesn't work, why? Where I'm wrong?

I'm trying also with

```
@reboot /usr/bin/wvdial
```

but no chance to get this work. How can I set up my crontab file to run `wvdial` successfully at startup?

When capturing the output from `wvdial`, I see this:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB1: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does root get any email (from cron) with output from the command that indicates an error?

Comment: it's my first time with crontab , how i can see if root get any email?

Comment: The easiest would be `sudo mail` (running the `mail` mail client as root). You could also change the job to log to a file: `@reboot /usr/bin/wvdial >/tmp/wvdial.log 2>&1`.  Then reboot and check `/tmp/wvdial.log`.

Comment: this is the output ` --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB1: No such file or directory` i have 2 usb to serial device 1 3g dongle and 1 gps

Comment: after system boot up the command work without problem , thanks for help